# Block a date based on counter in Sharepoint

Tags: calendar

I'm building a workflow where I would be taking the user's input(date for appointment), I want to take only 5 appointment's a day and after getting 5 appointments per day I want the date to get disable from the calendar. Pls help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to write a script to check the calender for each day to find out if theres any avaliable slots. Doing it in a workflow wouldn't make for the best user experience - also since you need to remove the date from the picker (when creating the item) you need to modify the Newform.aspx page anyway.

Personally I would use client side javascript for it on the NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx pages to guide the user up front before they are able to submit an item.

Comment: This is a good approach, but it’s worth noting a client side solution will do nothing for users that connect via outlook or any client that isn’t a browser

Comment: True anything but a browser requires changes to the application (outlook for instance).

Comment: Can I put any formula from sharepoint to block a date based on the counter of another field??

Comment: @Kajal Well I guess you could do that, but keep in mind the formula would need to return either true or false.